# jenkins 1.417 versus Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, jenkins

I have a brand new installation of Jenkins 1.417 on Ubuntu 11.6, trying to talk to an active directory. I have the Active Directory plugin installed.

If I leave off the base DN and password, the 'test' button claims success, while actual authentication fails. If I put in a user name and password on the domain, the test button fails (just as above).

Is there some tweak required to the AD configuration to allow something like Jenkins to talk to it?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the new active directory plugin which uses ldaps instead of ldap since 1.17 and your server doesn't support ldaps.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin

Solution: Downgrade to 1.16

http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/active-directory/1.16/active-directory.hpi